# Does S3 support HTTP pipelining?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pipelining

I have thousands of small files (about 1 KB) to upload to S3 every minutes.
If I upload every file in the loop
"send my HTTP request - wait S3's HTTP response - send next request - wait next response ...",
it cost lots of time because I have to wait 2 times of latency between S3 and my server.
Of course I already use HTTP Keep-Alive header.

So I try to send multiple HTTP requests without waiting for the corresponding (HTTP pipelining). I try to send 20 requests in a batch and wait for 20 response. I expected this may save much time because I can still sending request when the previous response on the way.

However, It doesn't make the world better.

I send my 20 requests in about 200ms, then I try to receive the response.
I expected I can receive response as fast as I send requests after I receive first response, like [this graph](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/HTTP_pipelining2.svg).

The facts is that after I received the first response, I have to wait about 300ms for every response. It doesn't get any better compare to sending one request and receive one response.

Why I can't shorten the time for pipelining technique?
Why S3 cost so much time for every request?
Does S3 support HTTP pipelining?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon S3 sports parallelization to get around the latency issue for each request.

You can make hundreds of concurrent requests to S3 and upload large batches of files in a very short time period.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/948461), the HTTP pipelining implementation in S3 violates the HTTP/1.1 spec.